# Sequelize not inserting into mysql database

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

using this code here

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const db = require('./models');

const { Item } = require('./models'); 

app.get('/select', (req, res) => {
    res.send('select')
});

app.get('/insert', (req, res) => {
    Item.create({
        name: 'Juan',
        price: 100
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
});

app.get('/delete', (req, res) => {
    res.send('delete')
});


db.sequelize.sync().then((req) => {
    app.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log('Server is running');
    });
});
```

i am not getting anything added to the database.  what i get is
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_NAME = 'Items' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'wishlist_app'
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `Items` FROM `wishlist_app`
Server is running

i tried different error and catch handling, didnt work. i expected data to be added to database or to get an error. i got neither

Comment: Do you get any logs from this code, by adding a console.log in the .then callback:

`app.get('/insert', (req, res) => {
    Item.create({
        name: 'Juan',
        price: 100
    })
    .then((item) => {
        console.log('Item added:', item.toJSON());
        res.send('Item added successfully');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error('Error adding item:', err);
        res.status(500).send('Error adding item');
    });
});`